# Admob ReferenceError for Interstitiatals and Banners on android

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to add a Banner and an Interstitials in my app.

I do everything correctly:
when i open up the app, i can see on the LogCat that everything is going well(i can see the request been sent), but then it throws this error every time:

---

04-30 17:00:59.952: D/WebCore(1584): Console: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: JSON line: 172 source: http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js

04-30 17:00:59.972: D/WebCore(1584): Console: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AFMA_getSdkConstants line: 1 source: http://media.admob.com/

---

Comment: What version of Admob are you using?

Comment: I'm using the last one: 6.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob 6.4.1 is not the latest version of the SDK.

You you now be using Admob from the Google Play Services SDK.
Try that instead.